# Local martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes

W is standard Brownian motion;
$Y_t = \delta_{1-t}(W_t),\text{ for }  0\le t < 1; Y_t = 0 \ \text{ otherwise};$
where $\delta_s(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac {x^2}{2s}}$
How to show that $Y_t$ is a local martingale?
This is my first time to touch a local martingale, really have no idea how to proceed with this one.

THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: How come the standard computation does not work? Consider $0\leqslant s\lt t\lt1$ and compute $E(Y_t\mid\mathcal Y_s)$ where $\mathcal Y_s=\sigma(Y_u;u\leqslant s)$. A first step might be to show that the sigma-algebra $\mathcal Y_s$ is $\sigma(W_u;u\leqslant s)$.

Comment: @DidierPiau I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Good. You might wish to write your solution as an answer.